# Loadbalancer should choose nodes by their capabilities (in terms of services)

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, soap

In our infrastructure we have several nodes with different capabilities (in terms of services). This is because the infrastructure where they are running on is not able to provide all types of services.

Now we need an intelligent loadbalancer that parses the incomming response (Soap) and decides on its content and on the capability of all nodes, which node should be elected.

Some nodes are not able to provide all services (a,b,c,d). E.g. if a request is "c", it should be forwarded to Node 2, 4 and 5. If the request is "D", it should be forwarded to 3 or 4.

Is it possible to realize something like this?

Currently we are using Spring and Tomcat 7.

Thanks a lot,
Christian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load balancing based on a registry of services is not a trivial thing.

Here is an example of a (non free) implementation

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0708_yaseen/0708_yaseen.html